# Pass a javascript variable in same page to a php function issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I'm trying to pass a variable named url from javascript to a php function called parse all within the same page, Here is my following attempt but it renders nothing. I'm also trying to innerthml the function parse as well. What I'm I doing wrong? Note:the function parse is cut out completely for sake of simplicity, It actually does more not just echo a variable, it echos more html.

here is my AJAX REQUEST inside a javascript script inside a php script.

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n".
 "\n".
 "// create and return an  XMLHttpRequest object\n".
 "function createRequest() {\n".
 "    var ajaxRequest;  // the xmlrequest object\n".
 "    try{\n".
 "     // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari\n".
 "  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();\n". 
 "    } catch (e){\n".
 "     // Internet Explorer Browsers\n". 
 "  try{\n".
 "      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject(\"Msxml2.XMLHTTP\");\n".
 "  } catch (e) {\n". 
 "      try{\n".
 "      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\");\n".
 "      } catch (e){\n".
 "         // Something went wrong\n".
 "      alert(\"Your browser broke!\");\n". 
 "      return false;\n".
 "      }\n". 
 "  }\n". 
 "    }\n".
 "    return ajaxRequest;\n".
"} // end of createRequest\n".
```

Here is my actual javascript, and the variable url that I want to pass and the innerhtml of the function parse

```
 "var spellcheck =  function(data){\n".
 "    var found=false;var url='';\n". 
 "    var text=data[0];\n".
 "      if(text!=document.getElementById('spellcheckinput').value)return;\n".
 "      for(i=0;i<data[1].length;i++){if(text.toLowerCase()==data[1][i].toLowerCase()){found=true;url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+text;document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:green\">Correct</b> - <a target=\"_top\" href=\"'+url+'\">link</a>';}}\n".
 "      if(!found)\n".
 "      document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:red\">Incorrect</b>';};\n".
 "      var getjs=   function(value){\n".
 "      if(!value)return;".
 " var url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+value+'&format=json&callback=spellcheck';".  // this is the variable I want to pass
 "document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='Checking ...';".
 "var elem=document.createElement('script');".
 "elem.setAttribute('src',url);".
 "elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');".
 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);};\n".
 "document.getElementById('resultdiv').innerHTML='" . parse() . "';\n".  //here wanting to innerhtml my php function
```

Here is my unsuccessful ajax JavaScript variable passing to my php function down below

```
 " var requestone = createRequest();"
        "var variabletosend = url;"
        "var vars = "deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(variabletosend);"
           "requestone.open("POST", "parse()", true);"
           "requestone.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");"
           "requestone.onreadystatechange = function(){"
           "handleRequest(requestone);"
           "}"
          "requestone.send(vars);"


 "</script>\n".
 "\n".
 "<form action=\"#\" method=\"get\" onsubmit=\"return false\">\n".
 "<p>Enter a species here : <input id=\"spellcheckinput\" onkeyup=\"getjs (this.value);\" type=\"text\"> <span id=\"spellcheckresult\"></span></p>\n".
 "</form>\n".
 "<div id=resultdiv></div>".
 "</body>\n". 
 "</html>\n". 
 "\n";

 function parse($url){
 print $url;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: added function parse note

Comment: Why is your javascript inside a PHP string? Is it being echoed? Why not just save the script in a `.js` file an reference it from your HTML document?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder your right, sorry for the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Mhh, your ajax call is wrong. You cannot call a php function with AJAX. You can call a php page, whitch has a php function. So you need to call your page with your param.
If you detect the param, then execute parse() , if not, echo the javascript code.

Assuming your code is in a page called "parser.php", here is a code that should work :

```
<?php
//We check if we have the param within the page call
$theDeletenode = false;
if(isset($_POST['deletenode']))
    $theDeletenode = $_POST['deletenode'];

if($theDeletenode)
{
    //The param 'deletenode' is given, so we juste have to call the php function "parse", to return the value
    parse($theDeletenode);
}else
{
    // No parametre, so we echo the javascript, and the form (without the quote and \n, it's much better)
?>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // create and return an  XMLHttpRequest object
 function createRequest() {
    var ajaxRequest;  // the xmlrequest object
   try{
       // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return ajaxRequest;
}; // end of createRequest

var spellcheck =  function(data){
    var found=false;var url=''; 
    var text=data[0];
   if(text!=document.getElementById('spellcheckinput').value) return;
      for(i=0;i<data[1].length;i++)
          {
          if(text.toLowerCase()==data[1][i].toLowerCase())
              {found=true;
              url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+text;document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:green\">Correct</b> - <a target=\"_top\" href=\"'+url+'\">link</a>';
              }
          }
      if(!found)
        document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='<b style=\"color:red\">Incorrect</b>';
        };


var requestone = createRequest();

var getjs=   function(value)
{
    if(!value) return;
    var url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+value+'&format=json&callback=spellcheck'; // this is the variable I want to pass
    document.getElementById('spellcheckresult').innerHTML='Checking ...';
    var elem=document.createElement('script');
    elem.setAttribute('src',url);
    elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);

    // Ajax call to this page, this time with the 'deletenode' parameter
    var vars = "deletenode=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
    requestone.open("POST", "parser.php", true); // parser.php : the name of this current page
    requestone.onreadystatechange = handleRequest;  // function to handle the response
    requestone.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    requestone.send(vars);

};      

  function handleRequest()
  {
    //here we handle the php page response by echoing de result of the php page (normally the result of the parse function) 
    try{
        if(requestone.readyState == 4 && requestone.status == 200)
          document.getElementById('resultdiv').innerHTML= requestone.responseText;
    } catch (e) {
        //Wrong server answer...
    }
  }; 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
<p>Enter a species here : <input id="spellcheckinput" onkeyup="getjs (this.value);" type="text"> <span id="spellcheckresult"></span></p>
</form>
<div id=resultdiv></div>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
// end of the javascript+form echo
}


function parse($url){
// this function is only called when the POST param is given
 print $url;
 }

?>
```

Comment: Hey CrtlX I entered this but I literally just get the php function spit out from the get go and the javascript and php arent talking to each other, here is what I get

Comment: Enter a species here : [text box] -link
find('table.infobox'); foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { $image[]= $element; } Print $image[1]; $data = array(); foreach($table[0]->find('tr') as $row) { $td = $row->find('> td'); if (count($td) == 2) { $name = $td[0]->innertext; $td = $td[1]->find('a'); $text = $td[0]->innertext; $data[$name] = $text; } } print ""; foreach($data as $value => $before ) { print ""; } print "
$value $before
"; } ?>

Comment: Sorry, i'd forget a line in the code. I missed the encoding part of the POST request. that line :
requestone.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 
I have updated the code sample with the right line. It's works fine now